# Path.Data binding for GridViewColumn.CellTemplate in ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, ivalueconverter

I see Ellipses in ListView if i set Path.Data like this:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Shape">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate >
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Path Fill="Orange" Stroke="AliceBlue" StrokeThickness="3">
                                <Path.Data>
                                    <GeometryGroup>
                                        <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="5" RadiusY="5"/>
                                    </GeometryGroup>
                                </Path.Data>
                            </Path>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
```

I try to bind the property of my class (object)MySymb.(string)MySymbName to this GridViewColumn.
And i would like to see the small geometric shapes like circle or square instead of (string)MySymbName.

I created ShapesConverter:

```
class ShapesConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var s = value as string;
        if (s.Equals("name01"))
        {
            EllipseGeometry ellips = new EllipseGeometry();
            ellips.RadiusX = 5; ellips.RadiusY = 5;
            return ellips;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

and I'm trying to bind Path.Data like this:

```
<Path Fill="Orange" Data="{Binding MySymbName, Converter={StaticResource ShapesConv}}">
```

And it doesn't work. Can you help me ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are there any errors or warnings written in the Output window when debugging?

Comment: Xaml - he does not like this binding - "Object Reference Not Set to an Instance of an Object", I trying to binding like this: `Data="{Binding MySymb.MySymbName, Converter={StaticResource ShapesConv}}"` - no errors but empty space in this listview column and converter doesnt work. I guess this binding is impossible... ?

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in your converter, what code path does it take? Is `value` always a `string`? If yes, you can replace `var s = value as string;` by `var s = (string)value;` - if no, write the following : `if (value is string s && s.Equals("name01")`.

Comment: The problem is that I don't get into the converter when debugging, converter does not work. In rare cases when the converter worked - value was Null_Reference. I refused "IValueConverter" and I added simple binding of <Geometry> propertie that I added in (obj)MySymb with only getter like this `public Geometry geomProp{get{ if(MySymb.MySymbName.Equals("name01")return new EllipseGeometry()...etc)}}` I guess this is not a graceful solution, but it works.